# uninitialized constant while calling ImageWorker in sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sidekiq

In my `Banner` model, I called this:

```
after_save :enqueue_image   

  def enqueue_image
    ImageWorker.perform_async(id, key) if key.present?
  end

class ImageWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(id, key)
    banner = Banner.find(id)
    banner.key = key
    banner.remote_image_url = banner.image.direct_fog_url(with_path: true)
    banner.save!
  end
end
```

The error I am getting in `sidekiq` is this:

```
2012-11-16T12:30:35Z 75701 TID-ows7fyu3w WARN: {"retry"=>true, "queue"=>"default", "class"=>"Banner::ImageWorker", "args"=>[6, "uploads/af-64b9e8b8c96a/770x350.gif"], "jid"=>"b8f23a2387f2b751"}
2012-11-16T12:30:35Z 75701 TID-ows7fyu3w WARN: uninitialized constant Banner::ImageWorker
2012-11-16T12:30:35Z 75701 TID-ows7fyu3w WARN: /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:54:in `constantize'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/sidekiq-2.5.3/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:37:in `block in process'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/celluloid-0.12.3/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:57:in `call'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/celluloid-0.12.3/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:57:in `dispatch'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/celluloid-0.12.3/lib/celluloid/future.rb:18:in `block in initialize'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/celluloid-0.12.3/lib/celluloid/internal_pool.rb:48:in `call'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/celluloid-0.12.3/lib/celluloid/internal_pool.rb:48:in `block in create'
```

Comment: This is in a Rails 3 app. So no require is needed - as far as I understand.

Comment: Any chance your banner model is namespaced within a module? If so, you'll need to prefix ImageWorker with `::ImageWorker` so it knows to look outside that module.

Comment: Nope. It's just a regular, vanilla model. `class Banner < ActiveRecord::Base`

Comment: Do you use `class ImageWorker` inside `class Banner < ActiveRecord::Base; end`?

Comment: @SergeyKishenin Yes...that's where that `class ImageWorker` was both declared and used.

Comment: Have you tried to put it outside?

Comment: Yes, I tried moving it into a `banners_worker.rb` file in `app/workers` but that didn't work. It started giving me this error explicitly - i.e. not just in the logs, but on the page.

Comment: Does it give you the same error?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem when several sidekiq processes are running.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old issue, but stumbled on it since I had a similar issue.

Fiddling around I've found this [issue on github](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/1043) which lead me to understand that I was doing it wrong, and having my workers on the lib folder.

Moving it to the worker folder solved the issue.